# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with ArrayList.addAll()

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory

I have a list of threads which I have paginated to use an endless scroll the issue I'm having (well my users) is an `OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a [x] byte allocation with [y] free bytes and [z] until OOM.` the x, y and z attribute is different per user but the cause of the bug is always in the same place and it's when I refresh the posts. I'm completely out of my depth here as I have no idea how to optimise my code or make it so this doesn't happen. As it's the biggest crash on my app at the moment. I've posted my `PostFragment` below please see the `refreshPosts(ArrayList<Posts> newObjects)` method as this is where the crash is happening.

```
public class PostFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private View mRootView;
private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ThreadItem mThreads;
private PostItem mPost;
private PostAdapter mAdapter;
private PostResponse mData;
private EmoticonResponse mEmoticon;
private PostFeedDataFactory mDataFactory;
private EmoticonFeedDataFactory mEmoticonDataFactory;
private static PostFragment mCurrentFragment;
private int REQUEST_CODE;

//Flip
private boolean isFlipped = false;
private Animation flipAnimation;

@BindView(R.id.postsRecyclerView)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@BindView(R.id.toolbarForPosts)
Toolbar mToolbar;

@BindView(R.id.threadText)
TextView mThreadText;
@BindView(R.id.flipText)
TextView mFlipTextView;
@BindView(R.id.shareText)
TextView mShareTextView;
@BindView(R.id.replyText)
TextView mReplyTextView;

@BindView(R.id.scrimColorView)
View mBackgroundView;

@BindView(R.id.fabMenu)
FloatingActionButton mFabMenu;
@BindView(R.id.flipFab)
FloatingActionButton mFlipFab;
@BindView(R.id.shareFab)
FloatingActionButton mShareFab;
@BindView(R.id.replyFab)
FloatingActionButton mReplyFab;

//Collapsing Toolbar
@BindView(R.id.postParentAppBarLayout)
AppBarLayout postAppBarLayout;
@BindView(R.id.postCollapseToolbar)
CollapsingToolbarLayout postCollapseToolbarLayout;
@BindView(R.id.mainImageContainer)
ViewGroup mainContainer;

//Back to top
@BindView(R.id.backToTopButton)
Button mBackToTop;

public static boolean isFromReply;

//FAB
private boolean mIsFabOpen = false;
private Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;

//Pagination
private int mCurrentPage = 1;
private ArrayList<Posts> postList = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean mIsLoading = false;
private boolean mIsLastPage = false;


public static PostFragment newInstance(@NonNull ThreadItem threadItem) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("ThreadItem", Parcels.wrap(threadItem));

    mCurrentFragment = new PostFragment();

    mCurrentFragment.setArguments(args);

    isFromReply = false;

    return mCurrentFragment;
}

public static PostFragment newPostInstance(@NonNull PostItem postItem) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("PostItemFromCompose", Parcels.wrap(postItem));

    mCurrentFragment = new PostFragment();

    mCurrentFragment.setArguments(args);

    isFromReply = true;

    return  mCurrentFragment;
}

public PostFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);
        initUI();
    }
    return mRootView;

}

private void initUI() {
    //UI Setup
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mDataFactory = new PostFeedDataFactory(getActivity());
    mEmoticonDataFactory = new EmoticonFeedDataFactory(getActivity());
    TextView textThreadTopic = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.threadTopic);
    TextView textNumPosts = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.numPosts);

    //FAB onClick Set-Up
    mFabMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    mShareFab.setOnClickListener(this);
    mReplyFab.setOnClickListener(this);
    mFlipFab.setOnClickListener(this);

    //FAB Animation Set up
    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fab_open);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fab_close);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.rotate_backward);

    //Toolbar
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_white);
    mToolbar.invalidate();

    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    //Load Parcel
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    mThreads = Parcels.unwrap(getArguments().getParcelable("ThreadItem"));

    mPost = Parcels.unwrap(getArguments().getParcelable("PostItemFromCompose"));

    if (mThreads != null) {

        if (mThreads.getName() != null) {
            mThreadText.setText(mThreads.getName());
        }

        if (mThreads.getTopic_name() != null) {
            textThreadTopic.setText(mThreads.getTopic_name());
        }

        if (mThreads.getNum_posts() != null) {
            int numPosts = Integer.parseInt(mThreads.getNum_posts());
            if (numPosts > 1000) {
                textNumPosts.setText("1K");
            } else {
                textNumPosts.setText(mThreads.getNum_posts());
            }
        }
    }

    postAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {

        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }

            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                postCollapseToolbarLayout.setTitle("Threads");
                mainContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                isShow = true;
            } else if (isShow) {
                postCollapseToolbarLayout.setTitle("");
                isShow = false;
                mainContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });

    flipAnimation =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.flip);


    loadData(true, 1);
}

private void loadData(final boolean firstLoad, int readDirection) {

    if (isFromReply) {

        if (mPost.getThread_id() != null) {

            mDataFactory.getPostFeed(mPost.getThread_id(), readDirection, mCurrentPage,
                    new PostFeedDataFactory.PostFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPostDataReceived(PostResponse response) {
                            mData = response;

                            if (mData.getItems() != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < mData.getItems().size(); i++) {
                                    Posts singlePost = response.getItems().get(i);
                                    postList.add(singlePost);
                                }
                                if (firstLoad) {
                                    mIsLoading = false;
                                    mData.getItems().clear();
                                    mData.getItems().addAll(postList);


                                    mEmoticonDataFactory.getEmoticonFeed(
                                            new EmoticonFeedDataFactory.EmoticonFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onEmoticonDataReceived(EmoticonResponse response) {
                                                    mEmoticon = response;
                                                    populateUIWithData();
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onEmoticonDataFailed(Exception exception) {

                                                }
                                            });

                                } else {
                                    mIsLoading = false;
                                    refreshPosts(postList);
                                }

                                if (mData.getItems().size() > 0) {
                                    if (Integer.valueOf(mData.getTotalPosts()) >= response.getItems().size()) {
                                        mCurrentPage++;
                                    } else {
                                        mIsLastPage = true;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPostDataFailed(Exception exception) {

                            customToast("Error: " + exception.toString());
                        }
                    });

        }

    } else {

        if (mThreads.getId() != null)
            mDataFactory.getPostFeed(mThreads.getId(), readDirection, mCurrentPage,
                    new PostFeedDataFactory.PostFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPostDataReceived(PostResponse response) {
                            mData = response;

                            if (mData.getItems() != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < mData.getItems().size(); i++) {
                                    Posts singlePost = response.getItems().get(i);
                                    postList.add(singlePost);
                                }
                                if (firstLoad) {
                                    mIsLoading = false;
                                    mData.getItems().clear();
                                    mData.getItems().addAll(postList);


                                    mEmoticonDataFactory.getEmoticonFeed(
                                            new EmoticonFeedDataFactory.EmoticonFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onEmoticonDataReceived(EmoticonResponse response) {
                                                    mEmoticon = response;
                                                    populateUIWithData();
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onEmoticonDataFailed(Exception exception) {

                                                }
                                            });

                                } else {
                                    mIsLoading = false;
                                    refreshPosts(postList);
                                }

                                if (mData.getItems().size() > 0) {
                                    if (Integer.valueOf(mData.getTotalPosts()) >= response.getItems().size()) {
                                        mCurrentPage++;
                                    } else {
                                        mIsLastPage = true;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPostDataFailed(Exception exception) {

                            customToast("Error: " + exception.toString());
                        }
                    });
    }


}

private void populateUIWithData() {


    ImageButton moreOptionsButton = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.moreOptions);

    moreOptionsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.thread_options);
            popupMenu.getMenu();
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.watch:
                            WatchedThreadsRequestData watchedThreadsRequestData = new WatchedThreadsRequestData(getActivity());
                            watchedThreadsRequestData.setWatchedThread(mThreads.getId(), new WatchedThreadsRequestData.WatchedThreadsFeedback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onWatchedRequestReceived(ThreadResponse response) {

                                    customToast("Thread watched");

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onWatchedRequestFailed(Exception exception) {

                                    customToast("Thread wasn't watched: " + exception.toString());

                                }
                            });
                            return true;
                        case R.id.shareThread:
                            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mThreads.getName() + " - " + Constants.LIVE_URL +
                                    "talk/" + mThreads.getTopic_url() + '/' + mThreads.getThread_url());
                            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                            getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                            return true;
                        case R.id.hideThread:
                            customToast("Hide: coming soon");
                            return true;
                        default:
                            customToast("Somethings Wrong");
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            });
            setForceShowIcon(popupMenu);
            popupMenu.show();

        }
    });


    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), mData, mEmoticon);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.setData(mData.getItems());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(paginationListener);

}

public static void setForceShowIcon(PopupMenu popupMenu) {
    try {
        Field[] fields = popupMenu.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popupMenu);
                Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper
                        .getClass().getName());
                Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod(
                        "setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener paginationListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        boolean hasEnded = newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

        if (hasEnded) {
            mFabMenu.show();
            mFabMenu.setClickable(true);
        } else {
            if (mIsFabOpen)
                closeMenu();
            mFabMenu.hide();
            mFabMenu.setClickable(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!mIsLoading && !mIsLastPage) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }

        //Back to top
        if (mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == totalItemCount - 1) {
            mBackToTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBackToTop.setClickable(true);

            mBackToTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0);
                }
            });

        } else {
            mBackToTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mBackToTop.setClickable(false);
        }

    }



};

private void loadMoreItems() {
    if (!isFlipped) {
        mIsLoading = true;
        loadData(false, 1);
    } else {
        mIsLoading = true;
        loadData(false, -1);
    }

}

private void refreshPosts(ArrayList<Posts> newObjects) {

        postList.addAll(newObjects);
        populateUIWithData();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.fabMenu:
            animateFAB();
            break;
        case R.id.shareFab:
            share();
            break;
        case R.id.replyFab:
            reply();
            break;
        case R.id.flipFab:
            flip();
            break;
    }

}

public void animateFAB() {

    if (mIsFabOpen) {
        closeMenu();
    } else {
        mFabMenu.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        mReplyFab.startAnimation(fab_open);
        mShareFab.startAnimation(fab_open);
        mFlipFab.startAnimation(fab_open);

        mReplyFab.setClickable(true);
        mShareFab.setClickable(true);
        mFlipFab.setClickable(true);

        mFlipTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mShareTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mReplyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mBackgroundView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mIsFabOpen = true;

    }
}

private void closeMenu() {
    mFabMenu.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
    mReplyFab.startAnimation(fab_close);
    mShareFab.startAnimation(fab_close);
    mFlipFab.startAnimation(fab_close);

    mReplyFab.setClickable(false);
    mShareFab.setClickable(false);
    mFlipFab.setClickable(false);

    mFlipTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mShareTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mReplyTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mBackgroundView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mIsFabOpen = false;
}

private void reply() {

    PreferenceConnector.writeString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "threadID", mThreads.getId());
    PreferenceConnector.writeString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "threadTitle", mThreads.getName());

    if (PreferenceConnector.readString(getActivity(), "authToken") == null ||
            PreferenceConnector.readString(getActivity(), "authToken").equalsIgnoreCase("skip")) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder loginDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        loginDialog.setTitle("Please log in");
        loginDialog.setMessage("You need to be logged in to reply");
        loginDialog.setPositiveButton("Log in", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        loginDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        loginDialog.show();


    } else {
        closeMenu();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), NewPostActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Threads", Parcels.wrap(mThreads));
        getActivity().finish();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

}

private void share() {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mThreads.getName() + " - " + Constants.LIVE_URL +
            "talk/" + mThreads.getTopic_url() + '/' + mThreads.getThread_url());
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}

private void flip() {

    if (!isFlipped) {


        mAdapter.clearAll();
        isFlipped = true;
        mRecyclerView.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
        loadData(false, -1);
        closeMenu();

    } else {


        mAdapter.clearAll();
        isFlipped = false;
        mRecyclerView.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
        loadData(true, 1);
        closeMenu();
    }

}

private void customToast(String toastMessage) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
            (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toastContainer));
    TextView customToastText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.customToastText);
    customToastText.setText(toastMessage);

    Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 25);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mData != null && mAdapter != null) {

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (mIsFabOpen) {
                    closeMenu();
                } else {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void updateView() {
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```

Thanks in advance once again.

Comment: Have you tried adding fewer items?

Comment: @bradimus I add 25 items as I get to the end until the max number of items has been reached

Comment: *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with ArrayList.addAll()* And what's you expected?... [your code in short](http://ideone.com/oVPUlu)

Comment: @Selvin yes, but I don't know how to fix this. I want it to stop when it reaches the max number of posts. I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: Do not add elements of itself to itself over and over again? (by itself i meant ArrayList) ... SO is not for question like ... *i get an error, here a code dump, fix it, please*

Comment: @Selvin is there a possibility you can show me how to do this please? Like I said I'm confused as to how to implement that

Answer (score 1):

Your problem basically boils down to this:

```
private void refreshPosts(ArrayList<Posts> newObjects) {

        postList.addAll(newObjects);
        populateUIWithData();

}
```

The list can only get bigger, never smaller.  If the server has lots and lots of posts, then `OutOfMemory` is pretty much inevitable.

One approach to solving this problem is to use an LRU (Least Recently Used) cache.  There is a utility class you can use: `android.util.LruCache`.

An LRU Cache is essentially a Map.  Items are stored with a key, like an ID.  With an LRU cache, you put new items in, but once a pre-determined limit is reached, old items start getting pushed out to make room for new items.

This will save memory, but make a lot more management code for you.

Your adapter, instead of having a list of posts, will just have a list of the post IDs.  This should be much easier on memory.

As the user scrolls and you collect more posts, you add the post ID to the list, and map the post into the LRU cache using the post ID.

When you bind to the list item view, you look up the post using the post's ID in the LRU cache.

- If it's there, great.  That's called a *cache hit*. Bind the post to the 
  list item view.
- If not, then you have a *cache miss*.  You have some work to do.

  - Start a server request to retrieve the post by ID.  I see your current code just retrieves blocks of posts, so you'll need some new server code here.
  - When the request completes, put the post in the LRU cache and let the adapter know your item has changed using `adapter.notifyItemChanged()`.  Unless the user has scrolled beyond it, the `RecyclerView` should try to bind with the list item view again.  This time, you should get a cache hit.

This is the basic idea. I'd write some code, but I still have a lot of questions since I can't see your model classes, data factories, and adapter class.

Once you have it working, you have to tune the limit on the cache so that it's low enough not to overrun memory, but high enough that your hit/miss ratio isn't close to zero.

BTW, I noticed that you are making the mistake of creating a new adapter and handing it to the `RecyclerView` each time you get a block of posts.  You should create your adapter once, keep a reference to it and update it.  Have a method that adds a block of posts then calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

---

Another idea for conserving memory is to use text compression.  If the problem is more a result of a large average size of the post rather than a large number of posts, you might explore this idea in addition to the LRU cache.

The concept is that you could take posts over a certain size, write them into a buffer using a `ZipOutputStream` then save the buffer in memory.  When it's time to display the post, you read the buffer with a `ZipInputStream` to uncompress the text.  Here the issue is performance as the compression/decompression is pretty CPU-intensive.  But if the problem is really long posts, this approach might be something to consider.

---

An even better approach: Only save the first part of the post as an "overview" display in the list.  When the user clicks on the list item, retrieve the entire post from the server and display that in another page.

Comment: This is brilliant, I'm definitely gonna do this route. Is there any links you know that can help me do this without the use of bitmap images? Thank you

Comment: For links, you can ask Google.  The principles are really just the same; instead of an image, you have text i.e. change `LruCache<String,Bitmap>` to `LruCache<Integer,Post>` and go from there.  When you hit roadblock, post another question to SO.  Replying to this comment with the link to any follow-on question will ensure that I see it.

Comment: Also, I updated my answer to talk about text compression as another option for saving memory.